# regex cut css links from html

Tags: java, regex, jsoup

I want to extract all css and js links from html page using regex, now I use:

```
([^ ()]*\.(?:css|js)\b)
```

that pattern, but it doesnt work perfectly, I wan to excluced symbols like '{}()}' before .css or .js path of link.
I try to use **Jsoup** parser but, he cant extract `<link..>` tags from js script inside html with code like:

```
if( userAgent.match( /ipad|iphone|htc|android|windows\s+phone/i ) ) {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css_pda54.css" />');
} else {
document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://static.gazeta.ru/nm2012/css/new_common_css275.css" />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javax [DOM Parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) since HTML is dervied from XML, or more HTML specific one like [validator.nu](https://about.validator.nu/htmlparser/) used by Mozilla.